# Which of these venn diagrams represents the given information

Tags: probability

I am told that $P(A)=0.18$, $P(B)=0.12$ and $P(A \cap B)=0.07$.

I have constructed two venn diagrams and I am having trouble with interpreting the notation. Does P(A) include those people who are strictly only A? If so,  my first venn diagram would be correct.

Or does P(A) include those who have A, but not limited to strictly only A, in which case the second one is correct.

And so, if a question asked me to work out the chances of having at least one of A or B, would I calculate it just by adding then numbers in each of the venn circles?

http://postimg.org/image/nt4v6ayjp/

Comment: In your first line I think you mean $P(A\cap B)=0.07$, right?

Comment: The second venn diagram is correct.

Comment: yes I mean the union.

Comment: Ok yes, with union you mean the intersection, right?

Comment: Ok and so the chance of having at least one of A or B is just 0.11+0.07+0.05, right? And yes I mean the intersection.

Comment: I am also claiming that the events are not mutually exclusive, simply because the middle part of the venn diagram is an on zero value.

Comment: Ok, then the probability of the union is by the addition rule: $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=0.18+0.12-0.07=0.23$$

Comment: Yes, your claim that the events are not mutually exclusive is correct.

Comment: Or, your way of doing it: $0.11+0.07+0.05=0.23$ is also correct!

Answer (score 1):

By applying the rule $P(A \cap B ) = P(A)P(B)$ we see that $.07 \neq (.18)(.12)$ which means the are dependents.

Your second diagram is correct